# Store User Rights in $_Session

Tags: php, html, session, mysqli

I've just tried making use of session for my login page and I wanted to store the 'rights' as well to enable or disable access of some page. Storing the 'user' works but not the 'rights'.

> ## Update: Got it working. Cheers!

Table:

```css
CREATEDATABASE`account`
CREATETABLE`profile`

id INT(3) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
user VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
pass VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
rights VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
```

Login Page/Session:

```js
<?php
 session_start();
 $user = $_POST['user'];
 $pass = $_POST['pass'];
  
 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "account");
 
 $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM account.profile WHERE user = '$user', pass = '$pass' ")
  or die("Failed to connect DB".mysqli_error());
     
 $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
 $right=$rows['right'];
 if ($rows == 1 ){
 $_SESSION['user']=$user; 

  header("Location: main.php");
  } 
 else 
 {
  echo "<script>
     alert('Username and Password not found!');
     window.location.href='logout.php';
     </script>";
  }
?>
```

I begin each page with:

```js
<?php 
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
$user=$_SESSION['user'];
$right=$_SESSION['right'];
if($user==true){
?>
```

Hope someone could direct me to the right path. Thanks!

Comment: `$_SESSION['right']=$right` $right is never defined

Comment: `$rights = $_POST['rights']; ... $_SESSION['right']=$right;` yeah you have a typo here.

Comment: Hello @IdontDownVote and @Havenard - should it be `session_start(); $rights = $_POST['rights'];` ..... `$user=$_SESSION['user']; $right=$_SESSION['right']; ` ?

Comment: You're vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks with that code, you should use prepared statements. Also user passwords should ***NEVER*** be stored in plain text form. They should ***ALWAYS*** be hashed

Comment: dont you want to put things in to a session on login, not pull them out?

Comment: Hi @SpacePhoenix - point taken. I'll revise it once I get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: Hello @IdontDownVote - that's what I'm trying to achieve but I guess its far from that.

Comment: Hi Guys, any reference that I can use to make this going? Highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First:
There's no need for the line below as the user will only enter his username and password. Take it out. 
`$rights = $_POST['rights'];`

Secondly, change this line:
`$_SESSION['right'] = $right;` to `$_SESSION['right'] = $role;`
You earlier set selected user right to the variable `$role` not `$right`

Comment: Hi @Chukwuemeka Inya - apologies, the second one was a typo. I've updated the script. I've updated the statement as suggested but it still not storing the `rights` as I'm trying to echo it. The username works fine.